# Same regex wont work on different input fields?

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I am having a problem with regex and some if statements . I have classic form with "**name**" , "**lastName**" and "**email**".

I am using simple validation with these *if statements*

```js
function addTask(e) {

    const filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/;
    const filterName = /[a-zA-Z]/
    

    if (!filter.test(email2.value)) {
        alert('please enter valid mail')


    }
    if (!filterName.test(lastName.value)) {

        showError('Please check your last name');
    }

    if (!filterName.test(yourName.value)) {
        showError('Please check your name');
     

    } else { 

        save(yourName.value, lastName.value, email2.value, text.value);

        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "testimonial";

        const div2 = document.createElement('div');
        div2.className = "pic";

        div.appendChild(div2);

        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "tormund.png";

        div2.appendChild(img);

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.className = "description";
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));

        div.appendChild(p);

        const h3 = document.createElement('h3');

        h3.className = "title";
        h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(yourName.value));
        div.appendChild(h3);
        
        cards.appendChild(div);

    }


    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
  
<input id="name" type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Name*" >
                                <input id="lastName" type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Last name*">

                                <input id="emailRev" type="email" name="field3" placeholder="Email *">
```

**name** and **email** if statements works perfectly ,they wont go straight to "else statement" and they stop running the function right away, but when it comes to **last name**, code continues directly to "*else*" and execute my card creation.

Also to mention, regex should be **only text** for both input fields. Does anyone knows where i get this wrong?

Comment: Actually your `else` block would be considered only for `!filterName.test(yourName.value)` if block. Moreover when is this function getting called? and what is the parameter?

Comment: That's what i thought at first, and you are probably right, but is there a way to get proper "if statement" check first, and then if all conditions are not met, then go to "else"?

Comment: It all depends on the answer to my next part of the question. You can use `if..else if..else if..else`

Comment: Sorry i didn't answer your next part of the question. I actually tried with "else if" just a couple a minutes before your answer and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your answer it helped me thinking :)

Comment: My bad :( I missed an accepted answer. But happy to trigger your neurons :D